# 18.04: How to install hindi phonetic dictionary?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, dictionary

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and am planning to move all my activities from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.

In Windows, I can type using English-Hindi transliteration keyboard with transliteration dictionary. That keyboard helped me to type in Hindi using English keyboard.

I am looking for something similar but have not been able to find one.I have installed Hindi (Wx) keyboard and Hindi (Phonetic) keyboard which works fine with some difficulty because there is no dictionary to assist.

Is there a English-Hindi phonetic transliteration dictionary for Ubuntu?

Comment: If you install the `ibus-m17n` package, log out, and log in again, a bunch of additional Hindi input methods are made available, such as _Hindi (phonetical (m17n))_. I can't tell if it contains what you ask for, but you may want to check it out.

Comment: Thanks the package ibus-m17n has the keyboard which I wanted but it does not install the Hindi phonetic dictionary...What I am looking for is this : When I type English words and I make a mistake then System puts a red line under it. I want similar thing to happen when I type using Hindi transliteration keyboard ... It should give list of possible words in hindi when I type a hindi word(using english).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add/Remove Panel Items
2. Add Keyboard Layout Handler and Apply
3. Right click. In Keyboard Layout Handler setting, remove the check 'Keep system layouts'.
4. in Keyboard Layouts listbox Add Nepali language for Hindi Phonetic.